# Declaring Variables for Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure that this is an easy question but I was wondering how I could declare different variables so that they become part of a where clause depending on what the user selects?

So for example I have an Excel spreadsheet with a combobox in it with a list of countries which are pulled from a database (United States, United Kingdom, Australia) depending on what the user selects it will go off and filter that data. The problem is in the data table where the query pulls back the results from the values are (US, UK, AU).

Maybe I could build a mapping table? I'm just sure I could do this by using declare.

Any advice on the best way to build this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cant you add an extra column to the table where the UK, US etc values are called Full_country or something and then filter on that so it matches what the user is selecting. Either that or re-write it in SSRS

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking for is

```
SELECT tbl.* 
FROM tbl
WHERE col1 = CASE WHEN @param='United Kingdom' THEN 'UK' ... END
```

What you may want to consider is a lookup table

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM tbl
JOIN loc ON loc.id = tbl.loc_id
WHERE loc.name = @param
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a LongName column to your table that will have the full country name values.

Another alternative is to have a separate Country table, change your other table to reference CountryID as a foreign key (instead of having a column with UK, US, etc.), and have your country table have ShortName (e.g. UK, US, AU) and LongName (e.g. United Kingdom, United States, Australia) columns. Then you could join on the country table to get the full country names.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: 
create a new dataset and store it somewhere (into a temporary talbe for example) then declare the varaiable and use the dataset as data source for it.

```
           declare @Country as varchar(50)
```

Use the variable in where clause to filter the result set:

```
           Select tbl.* 
           from tbl tbl 
           where tbl.country = @Country
```

In your case what the combobox should be based on the values which you want to use during the filtering. Thats why you could go with something like:

```
select distinct tbl.country
from table tbl
```

and use the generated result as source for your DropDown

Another way of doing it is by using CASE

```
  ,case when country = 'Australia' then 'AU'
   , case when country = 'United Kingdom' then 'UK'
.....
```

Thanks